# Symmetry of distribution function is defined as $f(x-a)=f(-(x-a))$, then expectation is $'a'$. i.e $E(X)=a$

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value, symmetry

I came across this statement in a book. While I know, how to prove  $E(X) = a$ is using $f(x+a)=f(x-a)$. I cannot seem to prove it using $f(x-a)=f(-(x-a))$. I keep going on in a loop, no matter what I do. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you please be more clear about what you want to prove?

Comment: Can you share your source? Currently, $f(x-a)=f(-(x-a))$ doesn't mean anything other than $f(y)=f(-y)$ to me.

Comment: I need to show E(X)= a

Comment: $f(x+a)=f(x-a) \not\equiv f(x-a)=f(-(x-a)) $

Comment: @Doubts did you think about writing the expectation as an integral, and imagining how this relates to a graph of $f(x-a)$ and the surface under the graph?

Comment: Would you get that $E[X] = 0$ if $f(x) = f(-x)$?

Comment: The expected value may not exist if $f(x+a)=f(x-a)$, and neither under $f(y)=f(-y)$. Example: Cauchy distribution. So in general the statement is not true, regardless on how you write it down. Obviously it will be true *assuming that $E[X]$ exists*.

Comment: In light of the comment by @Lewian, what you *can* prove is that $E(X)=2a-E(X).$ From that it follows that when $E(X)$ is finite, $E(X)=a;$ otherwise $E(X)$ must be undefined.

Comment: @whuber How does your $E(X)=2a-E(X)$ make sense when $E(X)$ is undefined?

Comment: @Dave It equates two undefined quantities.  That makes sense because (in this case) it is a deduction predicated on a false assumption; namely, that $E(X)$ *is* defined.